# terminal shows bot running but it is not on-line

Tags: discord.py

That's it. The code is pretty basic. The bot connects:

```
[brian@archlinux Recruiter-bot]$ /usr/bin/python /home/brian/Python/Recruiter-bot/Playground.py
2022-07-18 09:41:39 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
2022-07-18 09:41:39 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has sent the IDENTIFY payload.
2022-07-18 09:41:40 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: e4f5be1c300984bcf62930669c7cb32a).
RecBot is now running
---------------------
```

But does not come online in discord. This is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json

f = open('./bot_config/configdata.json')
data = json.load(f)
f.close()
Token = data['token']
intents = discord.Intents.default()

RecBot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents, description='Playground Bot')

@RecBot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('RecBot is now running')
    print('---------------------')

@RecBot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send_message('Hello I am RecBot')

RecBot.run(Token)
```

I don't know what else to add but I have looked at https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=send_message#discord.InteractionResponse.send_message.

My problem seems more basic though. Why is the bot not on-line? (BTW I have been experimenting a lot but this is the first time I had this problem.)

Oh and I do have the intents enabled in DDP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, your intents really aren't enabled. You have to activate them in the code as well. `intents.message_content = True`. Also I believe you want `ctx.send` rather than `send_message`.

Comment: Try this checklist: Does your bot have the correct token? Have you tried resetting the token? Do you have the proper intents enabled? Check the developer portal, something there may be causing it to go offline.

Comment: I "solved" it by creating a new application in DPP. And send_message seems to be what is used in 2.0 per the documentation.

Comment: to goose.mp4 I checked all that stuff and regenerated my token multiple times. Just starting from scratch did the trick even though it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It should be [`ctx.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context.send). Where in the docs do you see `send_message` being used?